# Nuxt.js при редиректе код ответа 301 вместо 404

Tags: vue.js, express, redirect, nuxt.js

Есть проект на nuxt.js 2.15.8 и vue 2.

Проблема следующая:

Нужно было закрыть доступ к странице на определенных гейтах. Написал анонимную middleware, но она выдает код ответа 301, а нужно 404.

Попробовал переписать в блоке asyncData

```
async asyncData({ req, error }) {
    const allowedHosts = ['хостнейм'];
    const isAllowed = req.headers.host && allowedHosts.includes(req.headers.host);

    if (!isAllowed) {
      return error({ statusCode: 404 });
    }
```

Теперь 404 код ответа выдает совершенно на другой url - [https://localhost.ru.test/app/хостнейм/?error=login_required](https://localhost.ru.test/app/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC/?error=login_required)

Никогда не работал с nuxt.js и даже не совсем понимаю куда копать. Подскажите, как добиться, чтобы при переходе на страницу получать нормальный код ответа.

p.s.

Заранее прошу прощения за такое малое количество вводной информации - не совсем понимаю, что именно нужно предоставить.